# Finding B.213 forms for Australian Nurse serving mainly in Egypt during World War I?

Tags: military-records, australia, world-war-1, egypt

This is a follow on question from [Interpreting Service Record of QAIMNS nurse in Egypt at time of Gallipoli campaign?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/interpreting-service-record-of-qaimns-nurse-in-egypt-at-time-of-gallipoli-campai) which could be referred to for additional background.

My great grand aunt [Eleanor Bessie Stacy (1879-1925)](http://nurses.ww1anzac.com/st.html) was a World War I nurse with Queen Alexandra's Imperial Military Nursing Service (QAIMNS) and later the Australian Army Nursing Service (AANS).

I have a copy of her QAIMNS service record ([WO/399/7869](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C10800727)) from The National Archives and a small excerpt from that is pictured below.

[image]

The last column mentions "B213" and my understanding from various web pages like [Researching Canadian Soldiers of the First World War](http://regimentalrogue.com/misc/researching_first_world_war_soldiers_part2.htm) is that the B213 forms are a "Record of promotions, reductions, transfers, casualties, etc., during active service".

Does anyone know if the B.213 forms related to an Australian Nurse serving mainly in Egypt during World War I are likely to have survived?

Comment: As far as I know B213 was a form relating to the field strength of a military unit,  so you'd need to start with the unit(s) she served in rather than with her.  See http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/ww1lit/collections/item/4090?CISOBOX=1&REC=6 for an example.

Comment: Many thanks for that link - I had not seen what that form looked like until then - I'll start making that list of her units and see where I can take it from there.  It does not look like a form designed for naming individuals so hopefully the QAIMNS re-purposed it to do so or that I can associate her movements with their reassignments.